# htaccess rules dont work on linux server

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu

On my development server running xampp on windows my .htacess rewrite rules are working fine. Once we went to our live server which is running `Linux core 3.8.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)`, our rules which do not contain parameters no longer work, yet rules which do have parameters are working.

```
    Options -Indexes 

    <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|txt|js|htaccess)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
    </filesMatch>

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

    RewriteEngine On    
    #Main site rules
    RewriteRule    ^login/?$    login.php    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^contact/?$     contact.php    [NC,L]
```

The above rules which go to contact.php and login.php do not work. But, this more complicated rule with parameters is working:
`RewriteRule    ^game/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$   handles/handle-game-select.php?name=$1    [NC,L]`

Is there differences between the two server environments which is causing this to occur?

Also, it appears that if we do something strange such as: `RewriteRule    ^contact.x     contact.php    [NC,L]` we are able to reach contact.php...

Very confused on this one.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that is due to enabling of `MultiViews` option. Add this line on top to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Thanks. Others who stumble upon this may enjoy this article aswell: http://blog.razuna.com/2008/03/27/apache-htaccess-and-directive-multiviews/